# Timer object doesn't start and execute Action block (Powershell 3)

Tags: powershell-3.0

In the script below an Action is linked to Timer object , but the Action doesn't execute even when Timer elapsed(2000ms).

What's missing?

```
***Console (No Further Output)-***  
14-08-2020 11:38:54 Action reached 
Id  -  Name  - PSJobTypeName  - State  - HasMoreData -  Location -  Command        
         
5 -Timer.Elapsed ----------   NotStarted - False-------------     Write-Output Get-D.....                      



***Script-***   
Get-event | Remove-Event
Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event

$Timer = New-Object System.Timers.Timer
$objectEventArgs = @{
    InputObject = $Timer
    EventName = 'Elapsed'
    SourceIdentifier = 'Timer.Elapsed'
}

$Timer.Interval = 2000
$Timer.Autoreset = $true
$Timer.Enabled = $true



Write-Output $((Get-Date).ToString() + " Action reached")

$global:n = Write-Output $((Get-Date).ToString() + "Action block executed")
$action = { $n } 

Register-ObjectEvent @objectEventArgs -Action $action

$Timer.start() #even calling timer start method doesn't trigger the action
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced Write-Output in the Action Block with **Write-Host** and the issue was resolved.

Write-Output pipes the output down a cmdlet and doesn't write to the Console .

Inorder to write to the Console, Write-Host has to be used.